# Cannot add text under image without the clear tag and text-align centers around contents, not page

Tags: html, css

For some reason text1 goes to the next column instead of under the image like it should unless i use a clear tag. The problem with using a clear tag is i cannot add text2 around where text1 was previously before the clear tag which is why you see a big space before the paragraphs.

Also text-align doesn't center text on the page. It centers text around its contents. How do i fix this?

Jsfiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/p6eocccj/

HTML

```
<div id="div1">
<p id="text0"><span id="sp1pg4">About me</span></p>
<img id="img1" src ="images/hack.jpg"/>
<br>
<p id="text1"><strong>Image Courtesy Homer Simpson</strong><br></br>
<a href="www.google.com">www.homersimpsoniscooltoo.com</a></p>
<p id="text2">
Hi there!
<br></br>
I'm bob, a coool designer and developer<br>
from Far far coolioland, Australia. I<br>
specialise in cooking, shipping, shopping,<br>
camping and turning coffee into popcorn. My<br>
approach to buytying is this, make it clean and<br>
simple but also focus on the buying for men. This<br>
is what differentiates poor people from great chimps.<br>
Whether you want to build a house for as long as<br>
business, a personal toy or just ask you some<br>
</p>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#div1 {
width: max-width;
height: 1650px;
background-color: #ECECEC;
}

#text0 {
text-align: left;
padding-top: 25px;
padding-left:150px;
}

#img1 {
float:left;
margin-top: 25px;
margin-left:150px;
width: 220px;
height: 220px;
border-radius: 50%;
}

#text1 {
clear:left;
float:left;
padding-left:160px;
font-size:13px;
line-height:80%;
}

#text2 {
padding-top: 100px;
line-height: 140%;
text-align: center;
font-family: sans-serif;
font-size: 15px;
}
```

Comment: Wrap the image and the text into a container element, and float that instead. (And while you’re doing so, have a look at the HTML5 elements `figure` and `figcaption` – using those would be a start in improving the currently rather crappy semantics of your markup.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because when you apply `float` rule to any element then that element is not part of Normal Document Flow and it will wrap texts around it. Either remove `float` or use `clearfix` hack.

**Here is clearfix hack-**

```
.clearfix::after {
  display: table;
  content: '';
  clear: both;
}
```

P.S: I have just removed `float: left` from image. If you want to use hack then apply `clearfix` class to parent of image.

```css
#div1 {
      width: max-width;
      height: 1650px;
      background-color: #ECECEC;
}

#text0 {
 text-align: left;
 padding-top: 25px;
 padding-left:150px;
}

#img1 {
 margin-top: 25px;
 margin-left:150px;
 width: 220px;
 height: 220px;
 border-radius: 50%;
}

#text1 {
    clear:left;
  float:left;
  padding-left:160px;
  font-size:13px;
  line-height:80%;
}

#text2 {
   padding-top: 100px;
   line-height: 140%;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div id="div1">
<p id="text0"><span id="sp1pg4">About me</span></p>
<img id="img1" src ="images/hack.jpg"/>
<br>
<p id="text1"><strong>Image Courtesy Homer Simpson</strong><br></br>
<a href="www.google.com">www.homersimpsoniscooltoo.com</a></p>
<p id="text2">
Hi there!
<br></br>
I'm bob, a coool designer and developer<br>
from Far far coolioland, Australia. I<br>
specialise in cooking, shipping, shopping,<br>
camping and turning coffee into popcorn. My<br>
approach to buytying is this, make it clean and<br>
simple but also focus on the buying for men. This<br>
is what differentiates poor people from great chimps.<br>
Whether you want to build a house for as long as<br>
business, a personal toy or just ask you some<br>
</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Because you add float left to to image tag..remove float on image or add clear to text elements